# Issues Parsing a Facebook Graph API JSON Message using JQuery $.each Function

Tags: json

I have been trying to access/parse the “message” object found in the JSON results hereafter, issued by the Facebook Graph API, using the Javascript JQuery $.each(function()) Function but without success. I am able to access the “name” object, but not the objects found in the statuses=>data array. I have tried a multitude of syntaxes, but without success. I was wondering if one could provide a syntactical example using the Javascript JQuery $.each(function()) Function of how I could access the “message” object. As you will notice, the “message” objects are found under the following structure: results=>friends=>data array=>statuses=>data array=>message.

```
{
  "id": "idValue", 
  "friends": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "NameValue", 
        "id": "idValue", 
        "statuses": {
          "data": [
            {
              "message": "Msg1", 
              "updated_time": "Date", 
            }, 
            {
              "message": "Msg2", 
              "updated_time": "Date", 
            },
          ], 
        }
      }, 
      {
        "name": "NameValue", 
        "id": "idValue", 
        "statuses": {
          "data": [
            {
              "message": "Msg1", 
              "updated_time": "Date", 
                }, 
            {
              "message": "Msg2", 
              "updated_time": "Date", 
            },
          ], 
        }
      }
    ], 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that that block is stored in `response`:

```
console.log(response);
$.each(response.friends.data, function(i, friend){
   console.log(friend);
   $.each(friend.statuses, function(i, status){
       console.log(status);
   }); 
});
```

Un-tested, but it should work. It helps to console.log along the way to be sure what you're looking at. See the log in the inspector in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Hi Ferrants,

Thank you very much for your time and answer. This has helped me parse the JSON Message.

Regards,

JF